# Android. Error related to the adapter in a custom listview

Tags: android, listener, adapter

i hope anyone can help me because i'm totally lost now.

I made this custom Adapter that populates a listview from a given list.

The problem is in the minus & plus buttons. They both have listeners that modify the textview in 1 count depending on which one is pressed, an also it modifies the source list.

Here is a picture [PIC](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/screenshot2012042120594.png) that ilustrate the final view.

If the buttons pressed in first place from the first row everythings works, you can then use the rest of them whitout problem. But, if the pressed are one of the others, the application crashes.

The error given is a nullpointerexception when trying to add+1 or remove-1 to the original list on a particular list item.

If anything more is needed please ask. Thanks for your attention.

public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;
private int mLayoutResourceId;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
     mContext = context;
     mLayoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
}

public int getCount() {
    return SavedMenuList.INSTANCE.size();
}

public MenuListItem getItem(int position) {
    return SavedMenuList.INSTANCE.getItem(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        rowView = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.confirmation_list_row_check);
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.confirmation_list_row_name);
        viewHolder.minus = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.confirmation_list_row_remove_button);
        viewHolder.minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MenuListItem item = (MenuListItem) viewHolder.minus.getTag();
                SavedMenuList.INSTANCE.removeOneItemCount(item);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        viewHolder.count = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.confirmation_list_row_count);
        viewHolder.plus = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.confirmation_list_row_add_button);
        viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MenuListItem item = (MenuListItem) viewHolder.plus.getTag();
                SavedMenuList.INSTANCE.addOneItemCount(item);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        viewHolder.itemid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.confirmation_list_row_itemid);
        viewHolder.typeid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.confirmation_list_row_typeid);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        rowView = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) rowView.getTag()).checkBox.setTag(getItem(position));
        ((ViewHolder) rowView.getTag()).minus.setTag(getItem(position));
        ((ViewHolder) rowView.getTag()).plus.setTag(getItem(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    MenuListItem item = getItem(position);

    holder.text.setText(item.getmItemName() + " (" + item.getmItemTypeName() + ")");
    holder.count.setText(String.valueOf(item.getmItemCount()));
    holder.typeid.setText(String.valueOf(item.getmItemId()));
    holder.typeid.setText(String.valueOf(item.getmItemTypeId()));

    return rowView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public CheckBox checkBox;
    public TextView text;
    public ImageButton minus;
    public TextView count;
    public ImageButton plus;
    public TextView itemid;
    public TextView typeid;
}
```

}

And this is the error:

04-22 02:54:22.398: E/AndroidRuntime(7112):     at giorgi.betaproject.utils.SavedMenuList.addOneItemCount(SavedMenuList.java:34)

```
public enum SavedMenuList {
    INSTANCE;

    List <MenuListItem> mList = new ArrayList<MenuListItem> ();

...
    public boolean addOneItemCount(MenuListItem item) {
        for (MenuListItem mItem: mList){
            if (item.equals(mItem)){
                mItem.addOneItemCount();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Well, it's solved. 
Can anyone tell me why it works with this: 
`if (mItem.equals(item))` and not with
`if (item.equals(mItem))` ?????

Comment: Changing `if (item.equals(mItem))` to `if (mItem.equals(item))` does not solve your problem, it simply hides your problem. `if (mItem.equals(item))` is just like `mItem.equals(null)`, which always returns **false** and is obviously not what you desired. The solution is provided in the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean addOneItemCount(MenuListItem item) {
    for (MenuListItem mItem: mList){
        if (item.equals(mItem)){
            mItem.addOneItemCount();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`item` in the above code is null, because you never set it in your `getView` method.

```
viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
    public void onClick(View v) {
    MenuListItem item = (MenuListItem) viewHolder.plus.getTag();
    SavedMenuList.INSTANCE.addOneItemCount(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Note this line: `MenuListItem item = (MenuListItem) viewHolder.plus.getTag();`, you do `getTag()` from the `minus` view, but you never do `viewHolder.plus.setTag(...)` in your code, which certainly causes NullPoinaterException.